# Error while using epstopdf

Tags: miktex, eps, epstopdf

I wish to  include eps images generated from Matlab plot (pdf is generated by Matlab as a whole page, that's why eps), however the conversion fails, leaving blank pdf image. The messaghe is:

```
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript

9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1



Sorry, but "MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter" did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\epstopdf.log
```

The content of the log file

```
2019-12-03 06:29:05,797+0100 INFO  epstopdf - starting with command line: epstopdf --outfile=images/kkk-eps-converted-to.pdf images/kkk.eps
2019-12-03 06:29:06,456+0100 FATAL epstopdf - Invalid argument
2019-12-03 06:29:06,457+0100 FATAL epstopdf - Info: 
2019-12-03 06:29:06,457+0100 FATAL epstopdf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Stream\FileStream.cpp
2019-12-03 06:29:06,457+0100 FATAL epstopdf - Line: 68
```

I have recently installed and updated Miktex and compile with LuaLatex.

Here is the  content of the eps, if needed https://pastebin.com/1Rq86vVC

What is wrong with it? I have no idea what to do about it.

**Update** 
First of all I'd like to that I do compile with `--shell-ecape` (from TexStudio)

```
Process started: lualatex.exe --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode
```

I tried suggestion from Christian Shenk. The command is

```
mgs.exe -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOutputFile=images/kkk-eps-converted-to.pdf - -c quit
```

I tried to execute it  in command processor. It creates a 0 byte pdf file and gets  stuck.

**Update 2**

I executed

```
epstopdf --outfile=images/kkk-eps-converted-to.pdf images/kkk.eps
```

And I did get additional information

```
Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
Operand stack:
   Helvetica-BoldOblique
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
-   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2015   1   3   %oparray_pop   2014   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1967   1   3   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:973/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:123/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
```

I have no clue how I can fix it. It mentions something about "Helvetica-BoldOblique", but the images don't use it, but regular Helvetica.

Comment: are you running the command with shell-escape? Could you give us a Minimal Working Example of a tex file that recreates the problem?

Comment: @EladDen you shouldn't need shell escape here (restricted epstopdf is allowed by default)

Comment: You can execute Ghostscript manually in order to get more information: `epstopdf -n --outfile=images/kkk-eps-converted-to.pdf images/kkk.eps` will show you the command to execute.

Comment: @ChristianSchenk I followed your suggestion and added updated with information about it.

Comment: @ChristianSchenk updated once more

Comment: I do not get any error. Make sure you have all packages mentioned here https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/112 installed, you are maybe missing some font.

Comment: The command you use gets stuck because it expects input file to be piped into. Try this: `mgs.exe -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOutputFile=images/kkk-eps-converted-to.pdf - -c quit < images/kkk.eps`

Comment: That was the lesson recently learned here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/393#issuecomment-543080026 :)

Comment: @ivankokan I have absolutely no idea. That is what epstopdf showed after executing commabd by Christian Schenk. 
But you were right about packages. Almost none were installed. I installed them and this solved the problem . You may post it as an answer for extra rep ;). I expected, however, Miktex to install missing packages.

Comment: @AndreyPro Your expectations were implemented in Apr 2020: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/429

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- About `-n` option

Christian suggested to use `-n` option to get the insight of the used command, e.g.

```
epstopdf -n --outfile=images/kkk-eps-converted-to.pdf images/kkk.eps
```

What you got is

```
mgs.exe -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOutputFile=images/kkk-eps-converted-to.pdf - -c quit
```

and it got stuck because it waited for the input file/stream (lesson learned here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/393#issuecomment-543080026).

So, running

```
mgs.exe -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOutputFile=images/kkk-eps-converted-to.pdf - -c quit < images/kkk.eps
```

will do.

- `Error: /invalidfont in /findfont`

I guess you do not have the necessary fonts installed within your MiKTeX. Make sure you have all the packages mentioned here https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/112 installed and try again.

EDIT: I had no problems with converting your file. Then I uninstalled only `helvetic` package and got the error you got:

```
Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
Operand stack:
   Helvetica-BoldOblique
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2015   1   3   %oparray_pop   2014   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1967   1   3   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:973/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:123/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Sorry, but "MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\epstopdf.log
```

**Therefore, missing `helvetic` package was the root cause of your issue.**

I also created an issue (actually a suggestion for possible enhancement): https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/429.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem:

**Step 1:** Remove the entire MikTeX exists on your computer using the Control Panel, after removing deleted folder named MikTeX in C:\ Program files (x86 ) to avoid errors when resetting because the same name folder (uninstall is complete without restarting the computer)

**Step 2:** Reinstall the MikTeX below (no need to install the program editor as texstudio, Texmaker, viettex, ...), this error is due to foundation MikTeX

MikTeX file download link: click [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bnv2g6paahb91vh/MikTex_2.8_NHC.rar/file)

After downloading, you unzip. Installation file named setup-2.8.3553.exe in directory MikTeX /setup

**Step 3:** Install the file setup-2.8.3553.exe as usual, remember to tick select Complete MikTeX to install the full version.

Note when using:

Note 1: The order declaring the package ordered to order from top to bottom as follows:

1. \ usepackage {graphicx}
2. \ usepackage {epstopdf}
3. \ usepackage {subfigure}

Note 2: Before running TeX files, please ensure that you have deleted the corrupted PDF files are output from run error before (just leave a tail .eps image file)

Coppy right: https://nhcan.wordpress.com/2020/04/05/loi-khi-bien-dich-file-latex-co-hinh-anh-dinh-dang-eps/

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to a known issue with the current MiKTeX package. See 
https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/112

A possible workaround that worked for me is to install the "helvetica" package (plus, any other font used by the Matlab code) using the MiKTeX Console.