# Latex does not compile eps files form Matlab?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, eps, matlab, epstopdf

I have problem with inputing **eps** files from **Matlab** in my **latex** document.

Matlab version is R2016a. Windows version is 10, editor is Texmaker 5.0.3, MikTeX is version 2.9.

The first case is when I use **latex + dvips + pstopdf** build option, with using **\usepackage{graphicx}**. As a result I got compiled pdf, it shows some eps files, but it does not show eps figures which i generated from Matlab. Exactly, it cutted my document at the place where I inserted eps figure with includegraphic command.

The second case is when I use **pdflatex** build option, with **\usepackage{epstopdf}**. It compile my document, without any cuts, only places where need to be figures from Matlab are empty. Caption of missing figures also exists.

I tried to generate again Matlab figures, even with different combination of extension, for example as -deps, -depsc, -deps2, -depsc2, but I got the same result. I am not sure is that some Matlab bug, or Latex?

When I open eps file from Matlab with GIMP, it has proper content, it exist, I cannot see why, after compiling, it is not in pdf?

This is log file, from the second case:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15QKyWGZxF5-QaZF6nDia_Ko8vNvKLzg6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you should use `.eps` extension, if it doesn't show then you should get a warning in the log, but you haven't shown the input or log so hard to say. Also avoid spaces and dots in filenames, especially on older latex releases)

Comment: I added link to log file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15QKyWGZxF5-QaZF6nDia_Ko8vNvKLzg6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: some warn pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./zaprez-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF inclusion: f
ound PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed  and some warn epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=slike/izotermsko/maliRe/brz
ine_maliRe_istiKne_ri1-eps-converted-to.pdf slike/izotermsko/maliRe/brzine_mali
Re_istiKne_ri1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 727.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.  which ones do not appear?

Comment: also you should update your miktex, you have a 2019 release but many graphics related packages (including grffext) are old and not updated

Comment: I updated MikTex, it is the same. From this part of text  which you put in comment brzine_maliRe_istiKne_ri1.eps does not appear. Part from where figures does not appear starts from line 704, aftert that line 711, 713, 715, 724...

Comment: did you update user and admin mode (in particular does it show grfext as oberdiek/grfext.sty or as grfext/grfext.sty in the log? note that you should not use epstopdf or grffext, graphicx on its own should be enough.

Comment: check pritisci_maliRe_razlicitiKne_ri1-eps-converted-to.pdf with a PDF viewer, does it look as you expect?

Comment: No, this file pritisci_maliRe_razlicitiKne_ri1-eps-converted-to.pdf is empty, there is figure in my dimensions but it is all white colour, it does not have content which I need. I updated user and admin mode, so in log file now i have grfext/grfext.sty

Comment: so epstopdf must have failed, try running it on the commandline to catch any errors, hard to help more with no test file

Comment: I understood that I need to use graphicx package with latex + dvips + pstopdf build, and epstopdf usepackage for pdflatex latex build, should I use graphicx with pdflatex latex build?

Comment: yes (it loads epstopdf-base.sty behind the scenes so you haven't needed to use epstopdf explicitly for the last 10 years or so

Comment: Solved, I had missing some fonts in MikTex, I concluded that with epstopdf command for single eps file when I read it log file. I installed missing fonts, after that deleted all pdf figures generated previously, and it works.

Comment: A lot about this has been done recently in MiKTeX. One issue and one improvement suggestion are still not resolved/implemented: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/112, https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/429.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while using epstopdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519027/error-while-using-epstopdf)