# miktex pdflatex epstopdf-pkg generating blank pdf

Tags: miktex, epstopdf, latextools, oberdiek

Installed the latest MikTeX on a new computer and the epstopdf package is generating empty PDF files. This seems to be a new issue as I am following the same process that works on my old computer that has an older version of miktex installed.

**build command output**

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def")
(test.aux) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty")

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file ./test-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF inclusion:
 found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
[1{C:/Users/jwalker/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./test-
eps-converted-to.pdf>] (test.aux) )<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/pub
lic/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 14016 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

**test.tex**

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test.eps}
  \caption{dummy data}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**test.log**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.3.4)  4 MAR 2020 21:21
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen135
\Gin@req@width=\dimen136
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def"
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-02-23 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count175
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)
(test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count176
\scratchdimen=\dimen137
\scratchbox=\box46
\nofMPsegments=\count177
\nofMParguments=\count178
\everyMPshowfont=\toks16
\MPscratchCnt=\count179
\MPscratchDim=\dimen138
\MPnumerator=\count180
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count181
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks17
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <test.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-03-04 20:55:55
(epstopdf)                    size: 38632 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <test-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=test-eps-converted-to.pdf t
est.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 8.
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=test-eps-converted-to.pdf test.eps)...executed (al
lowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <test-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-03-04 21:21:33
(epstopdf)                    size: 2518 bytes.


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file ./test-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF inclusion:
 found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
<test-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=1, 1163.34625pt x 698.61pt>
File: test-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use test-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: test-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on input line 8.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 345.0pt x 207.17548pt.
[1{C:/Users/jwalker/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./test-
eps-converted-to.pdf>] (test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1137 strings out of 481292
 16774 string characters out of 2917544
 247852 words of memory out of 3000000
 16697 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 30i,5n,25p,183b,209s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/pub
lic/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 14016 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 6 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

**OLD SETUP CMD WINDOW**

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def")))
No file test.aux.
(C:\Users\jwalker\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")))

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file ./enc_1-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF inclusion
: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
[1{C:/Users/jwalker/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./enc_1
-eps-converted-to.pdf>] (test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 34515 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

**OLD SETUP LOG**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.10.19)  4 MAR 2020 21:28
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
(C:\Users\jwalker\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count88
\scratchdimen=\dimen105
\scratchbox=\box26
\nofMPsegments=\count89
\nofMParguments=\count90
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count91
\MPscratchDim=\dimen106
\MPnumerator=\count92
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count93
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <enc_1.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-03-04 15:21:54
(epstopdf)                    size: 69831 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <enc_1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=enc_1-eps-converted-to.pdf 
enc_1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 8.
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=enc_1-eps-converted-to.pdf enc_1.eps)...executed (
allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <enc_1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-03-04 21:28:36
(epstopdf)                    size: 23405 bytes.


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file ./enc_1-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF inclusion
: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
<enc_1-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=1, 852.18375pt x 622.325pt>
File: enc_1-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use enc_1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: enc_1-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on input line 8.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 345.0pt x 251.94528pt.
[1{C:/Users/jwalker/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./enc_1
-eps-converted-to.pdf>] (test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1408 strings out of 492970
 20105 string characters out of 3135848
 80195 words of memory out of 3000000
 5304 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,5n,25p,273b,212s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 34515 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 6 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: You don't need the -shell-escape switch,  and loading the epstopdf package is not needed either. I would also suggest to give the eps another, more unique name . Beside this: to try to reproduce the issue we need the eps file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Hope the problem might be in the `eps` file, as your code seems clear, check with the another `eps`

Comment: _bangs head against desk_ @MadyYuvi I checked with a random eps file off the web and it worked. It appears the underlying issue is the update with the latest MiKTeX failed to install common fonts which prevented the MATLAB exported EPS file to be rendered. The following [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522597/latex-does-not-compile-eps-files-form-matlab) pointed me in the direction

The specific font packages I manually installed:
`
bookman
avantgar
helvetic
palatino
ncntrsbk
times
symbol
zapfchan
`

Comment: @jwalker Exactly!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while using epstopdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519027/error-while-using-epstopdf)