# eps files displayed as blank

Tags: graphics, eps, epstopdf

Having installed the latest version of MikTeX (2.9) and TeXmaker (5.0.4) on a new Windows-based machine, it seems that some eps files can be converted into an pdf format, but they are shown as blank, both in the "eps-converted-to-pdf.pdf" file as well as in the article.

Surprisingly, the same document works perfectly fine on my old machine, saying that the converted figures appear properly in the document.

I searched for some answers around the web, but none of the solutions work. I also tried a different editor, but the problem won't disappear.

Here is a MWE. Importantly, in this document "testfigure2.eps" seems to work perfectly fine, while for "testfigure.eps" the error described above occurs.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testfigure.eps} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testfigure2.eps} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Ideally, I am looking for a simple solution that doesn't require fancy refinements in my preamble.

Attached, please find the log file (had to change the names and save it as pdf) as well as the "testfigure.eps".

[testfigure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PObPG4KnvARn4Eg5LAYH-glQc5ug1Llz/view)

[logfile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WqEIJ1xmvqCrMN_yIfnqPSneNRcfsxn7)

Comment: Can you upload the EPS files somewhere? Plus it might also be useful to see the generated log file for this particular MWE (you can update your question and add the contents of the log to it)

Comment: Can you run `epstopdf testfigure.eps` on the command line (in the right folder)? Do you get any errors if you do that? Can you open `testfigure.eps` in a graphics viewer, such as [EPS Viewer](https://epsviewer.org/download.aspx)?

Comment: I edited the original post and added links to both the logfile as well as the testfigure.

Comment: No issues here running on texlive 2019 on linux

Comment: Just for fun have you tried other PDF viewers than the one build into texmaker? Just to rule out texmaker being an issue. Try e.g. Adobe Reader

Comment: @daleif Yep, as I said, the same stuff works perfectly fine on my old machine. I have no idea what the problem is. Do you think using texlive instead of miktex is worth a try? Also, other pdf-viewers show a blank page.

Comment: Not sure. Things should work on miktex as well. Firstly is your miktex fully up to date? Try deleting `testfigure-eps-converted-to.pdf` and have it create it again.

Comment: I have done that a few times. Still does not work.

Comment: Note my test did not have the second figure. Just to make sure, see if the iamge is still missing if the second figure is removed.

Comment: I have no problems to use your eps file. miktex converts it without problems. Do you have an external ghostscript installed? Did you try to run epstopdf on a command line?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what does "on a command line" mean? I have no external ghostscript installed.

Comment: You can go to your desired folder and click on the location bar of Windows Explorer. Then type cmd and press Enter key.

Comment: Thanks for this hint.

It says:

"C:\Users\ChopsChoc\Desktop\testfolder>epstopdf testfigure.eps
Error: /invalidfont in /findfont"

as well as

"Last OS error: No such file or directory
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Sorry, but "MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\ChopsChoc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\epstopdf.log
epstopdf: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates."

Comment: There is a long (and somewhat complicated) discussion on https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/393 that mentions this issue, which has resulted in a MikTeX update to version 2.9.7200 dated October 22, 2019. Do you have this version or newer?

Comment: If any newer version is installed, then font resources are missing. Solution: install all packages mentioned here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519027/error-while-using-epstopdf/519193#519193), or even more ultimate: install *all* packages containing .pfb files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while using epstopdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519027/error-while-using-epstopdf)

Comment: Thank you so much, everything works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Your MiKTeX is missing needed font resources.

Install at least all font packages mentioned here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/112, and you should have no troubles. (Even better, install all packages containing `*.pfb` files.)

There is a pending idea for MiKTeX improvement: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/429.

Check here as well: [Error while using epstopdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519027/error-while-using-epstopdf/519193#519193)