# Font in EPS file changes when converted to PDF in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, eps, epstopdf

I have an .eps figure (Fig.eps). If I view it in a .eps viewer, it looks as expected. In TeXStudio I try to include Fig.eps using includegraphics.

But in the converted file (Fig-eps-converted-to.pdf) the font has changed to a typewriter font.

The original font is Helvetica. I do not receive any relevant warnings. I have updated all my MikTeX packages.

Not sure what else to state here that would be helpful for diagnosing the problem - please let me know.

Comment: (1) Can we see the EPS? (2) Is the font embedded into the EPS, it it just refers to Helvetica then there might be issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some font resources, i.e. the fonts are not embedded in your PDF and therefore the visual depends on the viewer you use.

Install all needed font resources, and everything will be fine.

Check here:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519193/115879
- https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/112#issuecomment-577104722

Comment: That's it, thanks! For future users - I went onto the MiKTeX console and installed 'helvetic'. I then deleted Fig-eps-converted-to.pdf and built the pdf again, and it worked.