# Creating figure files in pdf version from eps files with proper fonts using psfrag and psfragfig

Tags: pdftex, eps, epstopdf, psfrag, pstool

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\psfragfig[height=83mm,keepaspectratio]{identical_distributions2}{%
\psfrag{p}[t][]{Probability of Error ($P_E$)}
\psfrag{s}[t][]{ Number of Sensors ($K$)}}

\end{document}
```

I am also using identical_distributions2-psfrag file with the content:

```
\psfrag{p}[t][]{Probability of Error ($P_E$)}

\psfrag{s}[t][]{ Number of Sensors ($K$)}
```

I would like to convert this eps file to a pdf file with proper labels as described by psfrag

https://www.file-upload.net/download-14433413/identical_distributions2.eps.html

I am also using shell escape as explained here:

http://www.epr.ch/brb/wiki/blog/enable_shell_escape_in_miktex_running_from_winedt

I am not able to get a correct figure file. The x-label is half cut and not displayed properly.

If I use this eps file and use dvi->ps->pds, all is fine. I couldnt understand what was wrong here or missing.. any idea?

Comment: How exactly do you compile? Under which TeX distribution?

Comment: My guess is that you are using MiKTeX and you do not have `helvetic` package installed. Update MiKTeX, enable package installation "on-the-fly" or with the prompt ("Ask me") in MiKTeX settings and try again.

More info: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537612/font-in-eps-file-changes-when-converted-to-pdf-in-latex, https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/393, https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/112

Comment: Hi, any progress?

Comment: @ivankokan hello. sorry for not being around for a while. I had much to do but now I am back. So your proposal was to install the helvetic package. I just checked miktex packages and searched for helvetic and it found it. After I clicked on it, it asked me whether I wanna uninstall it. So it seems this font is already installed.

Comment: Can you please upload the EPS file again?

Comment: @ivankokan I am sorry the like was valid for a week only. I found another uploading page and uploaded again. The link is updated.

Comment: Why do you use `t` for `\psfrag`'s `posn` positioning argument, is there any special reason? Leaving it empty will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the `\psfrag`'s `posn` positioning argument empty.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\psfragfig[height=83mm,keepaspectratio]{identical_distributions2}{%
\psfrag{p}[][]{Probability of Error ($P_E$)}
\psfrag{s}[][]{Number of Sensors ($K$)}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Abra kadabra style! This is a magic!)

Comment: Why did you use `t` for `\psfrag`'s `posn` positioning argument, is there any special reason?

Comment: Oh it was just a copy paste from a paper. I didn’t have any intention of using it.