# The gutter of 0.166 inches (smallest on pg. 3) and The font Helvetica is not embedded in the file

Tags: pdftex, pdf, format-files

I am planning to submit a manuscript through EDAS and I am using the IEEEtran class (conference option). EDAS gives the following errors:

**The file has 6 pages, has a paper size of 8.5x11 in (letter), is formatted in 2 columns, with a gutter of 0.166 inches (smallest on pg. 3), the most common font size is 9.96 pt, the average line spacing is 9 pt, margins are 0.680 (L) x 0.680 (R) x 0.675 (T) x 0.488 (B) inches, uses PDF version 1.5 and was created by TeX.**

I have looked up all the posts about the Edas and gutter problems but I could not figure out the problem. Also they wrote:

**Upload failed: The font Helvetica is not embedded in the file.**

Comment: Are you using some eps-graphics which could refer to helvetica?

Comment: No, I only used PDF and PNG figures

Comment: well pdf could refer to helvetica too.

Comment: Should I change the pdf to PNG ?

Comment: Sorry I can't tell you if this is sensible or not. You could check in adobe reader if removing the pdf changes the fonts, but you will then have to decide what to do.

Comment: You can try the trick of re-embedding everything: `ps2pdf14 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress %B.pdf %B-embed.pdf` suggested in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/My_submission_was_rejected_by_the_journal_because_%22Font_XYZ_is_not_embedded%22._What_can_I_do%3F

Comment: @stevGates Which TeX distribution do you use? And where do your PDF graphics exactly come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having all the information I need, but assuming you are using PDF graphics exported from MATLAB, I suggest you the following:

- export EPS graphics instead of PDF (in common fashion)
- ensure that you have all needed fonts (font packages) installed in your up-to-date TeX distribution (e.g. MiKTeX)
- `epstopdf` will take care of embedding all fonts

More information: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537620/115879

Comment: Thank you very mush

Comment: We still miss every information one needed to answer your question. Can you please fulfill to make this thread useful to the others?

Comment: @stevGates ????